# How to divide and merge jquery UI tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I working on divide and merge jquery UI tabs. [My Fiddle is](http://jsfiddle.net/CnEUh/2351/.)

MyCode:

```
$("#content_2").tabs();
$("#content_3").tabs();
var originalState = $("#content_2").clone();
$('#but').click(function(i) {
    $('#content_2 > ul li a').each(function(i) {
        $(this).hide();
        var spanVal = $(this).attr('href');
        var valueText = $(this).text();
        $(spanVal).hide();
        $('#content_2').prepend($('<div id="content_' + i + '"><ul><li class="ui-widget _lngTrans_Translatable">' + valueText + '</li></ul><span id="' + spanVal + '">' + $(spanVal).text() + '</span></div>'));
        $("#content_" + i).tabs();
    });
});
$('#but1').click(function() {
    $("#content_2").replaceWith(originalState);
    $("#content_2").tabs();
    $("#content_3").tabs();
});
```

Here I have two buttons 'divide' and 'merge' If I click divide the tabs separated with its contents.If I click Merge The tabs should come to original form.

The problem is first time its working fine but the second time when I click merge the **orignalstate** changing and goes weird.

Please anyone help me to create this feature in **Jquery UI tabs.**

If you need more information comment me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Change your function

```
$('#but1').click(function () {
   $("#content_2").replaceWith(originalState);
   originalState = $("#content_2").clone();
   $("#content_2").tabs();
   $("#content_3").tabs();
});
```

Here is Updated [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/CnEUh/2355/)